# Asp.Net WebAPI, как валидировать только структуру запроса, но не данные

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

Допустим, что есть такая DTO:

```
public class MyDto
{
    [Required]
    public string First { get; set; }

    public string[] Second { get; set; }
}
```

Вопрос: как валидировать только структуру запроса, но игнорировать `[Required]` поле (сразу отвечу на вопрос, что `Required` у него стоит для Swagger'a и убирать его не хотелось бы), т.к. дальше будет этим заниматься `FluentValidation`
Т.е. запрос вида:

```json
{"first": "", "second": []}
```

Будет валидный
А запрос вида:

```json
{"first": 1, "second": []}
```

Уже не валидный, т.к. first теперь имеет тип int, а ожидалось string, эту ошибку и нужно будет показать клиенту и не более.
Пробовал переопределить всё это дело через `ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions => InvalidModelStateResponseFactory`, но туда попадают и Required (и подобные) ошибки.
Использую Net 7.

Comment: Ну так уберите `[Required]` и валидируйте поле ручками в контроллере

Comment: Да тут дело в другом, не в валидации этих полей, а в валидации самого запроса, если мы вместе string закинем int, то нужно как-то адекватно об этом сказать пользователю